# boost::asio ioservice holds the rest of my code run

Tags: c++, qt, boost, boost-asio

i have created a windows appliation and i have used some QT Gui in that to display a Widget, so now i want to add boost::asio async TCP code to receive and send the data to another application.

when i write below code in my main(), this is what happens

```
//Code to initialize QT widgets and working fine.

try
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    server s(io_service, 8888); //8888 is a port no.
    io_service.run(); // **Even after successfull creation it doesn't look for incoming data**
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout << "Exception : " << e.what() << std::endl;
}

//rest of the code for qt widget, which will be blocked by io_service.
```

i have tried poll() as well to avoid this but it is also not wait for any incoming data.

is there any way to achieve both at a time??

Regards,
Jithendra.

Comment: Are you aware of [Qt Network module](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-programming.html) ?

Comment: @LeFlou , Yeah i came across that as well, since boost gives advantages when compared to Qt Network Module, we recently moved to Boost and it is working efficiently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`io_service` requires a thread of its own to not block other operations. also, instead of starting a thread on `run()`, there's an object called `boost::asio::io_service::work` that ensures `run()` is always executed, even when it returns.

here's how I usually implement io_service to run:

IoServiceWork.h:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

class IoServiceWork
{
public:
    IoServiceWork()
        : m_ioService(new boost::asio::io_service()),
        m_ioServiceWork(new boost::asio::io_service::work(*m_ioService)),
        m_ioWorkThread(new boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, m_ioService)))
    {

    }
    ~IoServiceWork()
    {
        delete m_ioServiceWork;
        m_ioWorkThread->join();
        delete m_ioWorkThread;
        delete m_ioService;

    }

    boost::asio::io_service& ioService()
    {
        return *m_ioService;
    }

    boost::asio::io_service* m_ioService;
    boost::asio::io_service::work* m_ioServiceWork;
    boost::thread* m_ioWorkThread;
};
```

Then I access my static global io_service object from any .cpp file from my project using this function.

CustomIOService.h:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

boost::asio::io_service& IOService();
```

CustomIOService.cpp:

```
#include "IoServiceWork.h"

boost::asio::io_service& IOService()
{
    static IoServiceWork ioServiceWork;
    return ioServiceWork.ioService();
}
```

it is put as a static object in a function to avoid the static initialization order fiasco.

So, then, all you have to do to create your socket, or any object requiring an io_service object, such as server in your case:

```
#include <CustomIoService.h>

server s(IOService(), 8888);
```

Comment: "that ensures run() is always executed, even when it returns" - what

Comment: creating a global singleton for this is not the best advice IMO and is overly specific. You can explain all that without the unnecessary design implications

Comment: @J-Mik you saved my day, Thanks for your reply, That worked.

Comment: Just for my knowledge, what if i am writing a DLL and want to use the same design shown above, will it work????

Comment: @J-Mik , i have tried the same in my DLL, sorry to say but it doesn't work , its throwing "Access Violation Error". i want DLL receive and send the values via network, how to achieve it?? any ideas.